# How can I bind already existing socket in Python 2.7 on Linux?

Tags: python, sockets

How can I sending packets through socket which I already created in my browser? I don't want to create new socket in Python, only bind socket as I mentioned earlier.

Comment: This question doesn't make sense. Are you sure you understand sockets, binding, processes, and file descriptors?

Comment: Maybe I used bad words. I want do something like wpe pro. This program can bind process in browser and sending packets. I want to sending packets in Python. Socket already exist in my browser, I want to bind this socket and sending packets in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot overtake an existing TCP connection from within another process without cooperation of the original process. With cooperation there are at least on UNIX like systems ways to transfer open file descriptors between processes. But to get this cooperation you would need to make changes to the browser.

But, your problem sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You should better ask about the original issue leading to this question.